# Gradient for a max-pooling layer for an input batch

Tags: conv-neural-network

I have been studying Convolutional Neural Networks and I have a question that, AFAIK, there is no answer for it (in Google, at least :P):

I already know what happens when doing backpropagation in a max-pooling unit: You just allow the backpropagation procedure to continue to input nodes with response equal to the maximum response received in the max-pooling unit. But what should we do when we are dealing with a batch of inputs??? This time, we will end up with a list of maximum values per max-pooling unit. What should I do then? Should I just allow backpropagation to the input node that had the maximum response most of the times in the list? Or what? Or should I just use online learning when I include max-pooling layers?